# PHP foreach loop messes up my in_array function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've written a script that checks bulk input of names received via a textarea and omits all values that are already in the database. It works if you enter just one repeated name. If you enter two or more, it will filter out the first repeated name, treat the rest as unique names and insert them in the database. I can't figure out why.

Firstly, this is an array that is built in another part of the script. It's generated from a database query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => john
    [1] => peter
    [2] => max
    [3] => jake
)
```

This array is referred to as $onlyHandles. Then this is the script:

```
if((isset($_POST['extract']) && !empty($_POST['extract']))){
    $handles = trim($_POST['extract']);
    $handles = explode("\n", $handles);

        if(count($handles)>200){
            echo 'error';
            exit(1);
        }

        foreach($handles as $handle) {
            $handleRep = strtolower(str_replace('@','',$handle));
            $handleClean = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?&"<>=+-#%$|'), ' ', $handleRep, $count);

                if ($count > 0) {
                    echo 'error';
                    exit(1);
                }
                else{

                    if (in_array($handleClean, $onlyHandles)){
                        $delmessage .= "<p>".$handleClean." is already in your list.</p>";
                    }
                    else{
                        $sqlIns = "INSERT INTO...blah blah blah)";
                        $resultIns = mysql_query($sqlIns);
                        $resInsArr[] = array($resultIns);

                    }
                }
        }
        $countresIns = count($resInsArr);
            if ($countresIns > 0){
                $delmessage .= "<p>User(s) added to list succesfully!</p>" ;
            }
}
```

Now, if you enter "john" in the textarea, it will shout that the name already exists. If you enter "john" and "max" it will omit john and add max.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. regarding the query format, I know, I know, thanks!

Comment: Hello ! I think that you must `trim` your `$handle` variable too because it's possible to have some spaces around it...
Then about your problem, I don't understand it. Your code seems "clean", maybe you should consider set the `strict` flag to true [see function definition here](https://secure.php.net/in_array).

Comment: Of course, you can make a really more efficient process using the array intersection functions and a multi insert. It'll allow to save processing time and simplify this code.

Comment: Take a look at [array_diff](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) !

Comment: This statement `$handleClean = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?&"<>=+-#%$|'), ' ', $handleRep, $count);` looks very fishy. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, that statement is not very fishy, it's just redundant. He's trying to replace all special characters within inputted string

Comment: @HanzoHasashi, what if user will input the string such as "john max john" without line break ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I was talking about replacing with space here, `str_split('\\/:*?&"<>=+-#%$|'), ' ', ...`

Comment: @shulard, thank you, looks like a solution. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, that doesn't matter. It detects a disallowed character, displays an error and dies. I can replace it with a space or a flourish, the string won't go anywhere coz the script dies in the next line if this condition is met.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, you're making a very good point. I'll fix it. What do you mean "redundant" I tested it and it works. Tried posting a hack string and it stopped as intended. :)

Comment: @HanzoHasashi, yes, the point is that you are making replacement just for counting the number of produced replacements. And it doesn't matter if there was a single replacement or many replacements - the code will end up with error. So I suggest you to just verify the occurrence of special characters in processed word

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give U some idea about how to achieve it:

1. Replace the first line:

   if((isset($_POST['extract']) && !empty($_POST['extract']))){

through

```
if((!empty($_POST['extract']))){
```

because `!empty` already guives U the guaranty that it `isset`

2. I am suspescting some special chars in play

U could also use the power of Regular Expression to replace the unneeded chars
in replacing:

Line 12: `$handleClean = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?&"<>=+-#%$|'), ' ', $handleRep, $count);`

Through:

`$handleClean = preg_replace("/\[\/:\*?&\"<>=\+-#%\$\|\]*/", ' ', $handleRep, $count);`

3. In Ur For-Loop, what about refactoring the following lines:

line 2: `$handles = trim($_POST['extract']);`

through (trim is not necessary hier)

`$handles = $_POST['extract'];`

AND

line 11: `$handleRep = strtolower(str_replace('@','',$handle));`

through

`$handleRep = trim(strtolower(str_replace('@','',$handle)));`

Hey ;-),

U should also add some print_r(...) to debug each step

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Ulrich Tevi Horus that made my code a bit cleaner but didn't solve the mysteriously disappearing users.
@shulard, you should post this as an answer to get the upvote. array_diff was indeed the best solution.
Here's the final code. Needs some tidying up but it's good enough to go on my server for testing.

```
//this is the current contents of the list:
$onlyHandles = array();
foreach ($organizedArray as $key2 => $val2) {
    $onlyHandles[] = $val2['name'];
}
echo "<br>begin onlyhandles<br>";
print_r($onlyHandles);
echo "<br>end onlyhandles<br>";
//finish preparation for display    

//if names submitted for the list list
if(!empty($_POST['extract'])){
    $handles = trim($_POST['extract']);
    $handles = explode("\n", $handles); //this is now an array
    echo "<br>begin handles<br>";
    print_r($handles);
    echo "<br>end handles<br>";
    //$countInput = count($handles);

        if($countInput>200){
            echo '<p style="color:red;">Please Enter fewer than 200 names!</p>';
            exit(1);
        }
        else{

            $handleFinal = array();
                foreach($handles as $handle) {
                    //$handleRep = strtolower(str_replace('@','',$handle));
                    $handleRep = trim(strtolower(str_replace('@','',$handle)));
                    $handleClean = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?&"<>=+ -#%$|'), 'p', $handleRep, $count);
                    //$handleClean = preg_replace("/\[\/:\*?&\"<>=\+-#%\$\|\s+\]*/", ' ', $handleRep, $count);
                    echo "handleClean: ".$handleClean."<br>";

                        if ($count > 0) {
                            echo '<p style="color:red;">Your input contained special characters.</p>';
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        else{
                                $handleFinal[] = $handleClean;
                        }
                }//end foreach

        }//finish checking count input number

    echo "<br>begin handleFinal<br>";
    print_r($handleFinal);
    echo "<br>end handleFinal<br>";

    $countFinal = count($handleFinal);
    echo "<br>countfinal is ".$countFinal."<br>";
    //check if this user is already in the list
    $handleDiffs = array_diff($handleFinal,$onlyHandles);

    echo "<br>begin handlediffs<br>";
    print_r($handleDiffs);
    echo "<br>end handlediffs<br>";

        foreach($handleDiffs as $handleDiff) {
            $sqlIns = "blah blah blah";
            $resultIns = mysql_query($sqlIns);
            $resInsArr[] = array($resultIns);

        }

    $countresIns = count($resInsArr);
        if ($countresIns > 0){
            $delmessage .= "<p>User(s) added to the list succesfully!</p>" ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I post my [comment answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021852/php-foreach-loop-messes-up-my-in-array-function/36046735#comment57770658_35021852) as a real answer :)

You must trim your `$handle` variable too because it's possible to have some spaces around it...

Then about your problem, I don't understand it. Your code seems "clean", maybe you should consider set the `strict` flag to `true` see [function definition here](https://secure.php.net/in_array).